# Is it possible to create utilities in Tailwind for specific screens?

Tags: tailwind-css

Having followed [the guidance](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints/#styling-for-print) on how to create print-specific modifiers, is it possible to use that to create or modify components for that screen?

For example, I have

```css
    .card {
        @apply rounded shadow bg-white p-3;
    }
```

I'm thinking of something like the following, but this isn't it - what should I be doing?

```css
    .card:print {
        @apply rounded border border-black bg-white p-3;
    }
```

Comment: Examples of use - modify specific components to be printer friendly, hide all action buttons, invert items that have dark backgrounds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use media queries for this

```
@media print {
    .card {
        @apply rounded border border-black bg-white p-3;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried so many ways, and I was convinced I had tried this. But, thank you - this is the answer! Not too clear in the documentation I think.